# Custom UnmarshalJSON for custom time format returning this {0 63082400645 <nil>} instead of time with ShouldBindJSON from Gin gonic

Tags: go, go-gin

I have this type and handler

```golang
type Bday time.Time

func (mt *Bday) UnmarshalJSON(bs []byte) (err error) {
    var t time.Time
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z0700" // RFC3339
    s := strings.Trim(string(bs), `"`)

    t, err = time.Parse(layout, s)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *mt = Bday(t)

    return
}

func (mt Bday) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    timestamp := time.Time(mt)
    return json.Marshal(timestamp)
}

type LoginHandler struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

func (l *LoginHandler) Signup(c *gin.Context) {
    // Verify name, lastName, email, password, gender, birthDate
    var user User


    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&user); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(user.Password), 8)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    user.Password = string(hashedPassword)
    fmt.Println("User", user)
    // Save to db
    l.db.Debug().Model(&models.User{}).Create(&user)

    // Return code 201
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{"message": "User created successfully!"})
}
```

This is the User

```
type User struct {
    Password  string    `json:"password"`
    Email     string    `json:"email"`
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    LastName  string    `json:"last_name"`
    Bday      Bday      `json:"bday"`
    Gender    string    `json:"gender"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt time.Time `json:"deleted_at"`
}
```

When I print User in the handler I get this for the Bday field

`{0 63082400645 <nil>}`

This is the full println

```
User {$2a$08$uTE7Llc6YM2owu.D6UWqpOcOVFHRFRrSxbkxWV4ecR72G6kK5/SNq d.n.m@gmail.com
Antonio Magalhães {0 63082400645 <nil>} M 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01
00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}
```

What I expected whas that Bday were something like a date
`2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`

Can somebody help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom type `Bday` satisfies neither [`Formatter`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Formatter) nor [`Stringer`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Stringer) interface, and thus gets printed as a compound struct (the fields of the underlying `time.Time` struct are printed individually).

An easy fix would be to implement a `String()` method, for example delegating to `MarshalJSON`:

```
func (mt Bday) String() string {
    b, _ := mt.MarshalJSON()
    return string(b)
}
```

For more details on how `fmt.Println` works refer to [`fmt` package](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) documentation.